# Two side by side divs, fluid with max width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I would like to have two side-by-side DIVs, in which the left DIV will always have text, and the right DIV may or may not have text (if it doesn't have text, it will have no content at all).

**If the right DIV has text** ... the width of the left DIV should expand to equal the width of its text, but only up to 50% of the width of the parent DIV.

**If the right DIV does not have text** ... the width of the left DIV should expand to equal the width of its text, up to 100% of the width of the parent DIV.

**In either case** if there is too much text to fit on one line of the DIV, it should wrap to the next line.

Is this possible using straight CSS? Or will I have to do a Javascript solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Why all the down votes? This seems like a perfectly valid question to ask. Maybe a couple pictures would help crystalize what he is looking for, but I don't see the need to punish him for not supplying that.

Comment: its just that people hate it when there is no mention of tried solution, also doing that violates guidelines.

Comment: Give him a break, it's a totally valid question.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this with both css and whatever scripting language you are using to populate the page.

Here's the sudo

```
if right-div-content-exists
    create left div with style="width:50%";
    create right div with style="width:x%";
else        
    create left div with style="width:100%";
```

Answer (score 0):

So I started thinking for a solution and somehow JavaScript plays a role.

I created [an example jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/priyaranjan/r8mPa/) that works the way you asked for.

Code:

```
/* html */

<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>

/* css */

.left{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    outline: solid 1px #666;
}

.right{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    outline: solid 1px #666;
}

/* js */

if($('.right').text()){
    $('.left').css('width', '50%');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with only CSS:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="right">Maybe text, maybe no</div>
    <div class="left">Always text here</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hBAHt/2/